# JOGL four blank initial frames

Tags: frame, jogl

In JOGL, there is the addGLEventListener; I added a listener to it.
When the display() "callback on gl" is called, the screen is printed in black, but after four frames the `display()` prints something.

How to make `display()` print something on the first callback `display()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you application implements an interface GLEventListener, there is always a next sequence:
—init();
—reshape();
—display().

In my opinion, you have a wrong drawing sequence in the function display().

Try do it in this way:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    gl = drawable.getGL();

    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POLYGON);
    gl.glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glEnd();

    drawable.swapBuffers(); // — it's for double buffering
}
```